# sequelize query to javascript .map

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize and a .map function to return all posts as below.

```
async function getAll() {
    const posts = await db.Post.findAll({
   
});
    return posts.map(x => postDetails(x));
}



function postDetails(post) {
    const { id, title, postText, accountId, createdAt, updatedAt } = post;
    return { id, title, postText, accountId, createdAt, updatedAt };
}
```

This is all works fine but I now I want to return a bit more info about the user of the post.  So I am trying to use the include method as below to eventually get the username of the account.  This doesn't provide an error but it also dosen't provide the username.

```
async function getAll() {
    const posts = await db.Post.findAll({
    
    include: [{
        model: db.Account,
    }]
    
});
    return posts.map(x => postDetails(x));
}



function postDetails(post) {
    const { id, title, postText, accountId, createdAt, updatedAt, username } = post;
    return { id, title, postText, accountId, createdAt, updatedAt, username };
}
```

From the logging I can see its providing the account information in an array???

```
  post {
    dataValues: {
      id: 2,
      title: 'test title',
      postText: 'test post content',
      created: 2021-05-04T13:58:08.000Z,
      updated: null,
      accountId: 1,
      account: [account]
```

I then drill down to only include the username and I do get an error:

```
async function getAll() {
    const posts = await db.Post.findAll({
    
    include: [{
        model: db.Account,
        include: db.Account.username
    }]
    
});
    console.log(posts)
    return posts.map(x => postDetails(x));
}



function postDetails(post) {
    const { id, title, postText, accountId, createdAt, updatedAt, username } = post;
    return { id, title, postText, accountId, createdAt, updatedAt, username };
}

{"message":"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"}
```

relations

```
db.Account.hasMany(db.Post, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
db.Post.belongsTo(db.Account);
```

edit:  I tried removing the .map function and get the same error.  If I remove the second include statement and the map statement it returns the post and all the associated account details but I just want the username and then ideally to map it.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: is db.Account.username a text attribute or a foreign key?

Comment: db.Account.username is a text attribute: username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set an alias for your relation: `db.Post.belongsTo(db.Account, { as: 'account' });` to get the account as Post "attribute" (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#association-aliases--amp--custom-foreign-keys).

try with this:

```js
async function getAll() {
    const posts = await db.Post.findAll({
    
    include: [{
        association: 'account', // association alias
        attributes: ['username'], // username is just an attribute
        required: true, // inner join instead of left join (post without account are discarded)
    }]
    
});
    console.log(posts)
    return posts.map(x => postDetails(x));
}



function postDetails(post) {
    const { id, title, postText, accountId, createdAt, updatedAt, account } = post;
    return { id, title, postText, accountId, createdAt, updatedAt, username: account.username }; // username is an account attribute
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much this worked exactly how you posted it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `account: [account]` is an array. So It's likely that you'll have to check the first item of the `account` array to get to the `username` property:

```js
function postDetails(post) {
    const { 
      id, 
      title, 
      postText, 
      accountId, 
      createdAt, 
      updatedAt, 
      account 
    } = post;

    return { 
      id, 
      title, 
      postText, 
      accountId, 
      createdAt, 
      updatedAt, 

      // Also check that account has an item in it just in case...
      username: account.length > 0 && account[0].username 
    };
}
```

You might want to add extra checking in case there's more than one item in `account`, depending on the data you're expecting.

One other thing I'd do for bonus points is just add `postDetails` to the map function, no need to pass the `x` arg:

```js
return posts.map(postDetails);
```

I think this is called **point free** style.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Your point free style does work and makes it a lot easier to read thanks very much.  The other answer resolved my problem.

Comment: Yeah fair play, mine was just a guess

Comment: Oh and btw, any answers that are correct, you can still give them an upvote ;)